# ThreeJS InstancedBufferGeometry Culling Issue?

Tags: three.js

When I render 3000 instances of my model and keep them in the view area i get 55FPS, But If i have 5000 instances of my model but keep 2000 of them Way outside the view area, I still get 40 FPS.

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000);

Is it possible it is culling correctly but just the fact it has to determine if its being culled whats slowing it down? I mostly pulled from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic.html

Edit* I know i can use     geometry.maxInstancedCount = trackCount; this is helpful but its not quite the same thing as culling, as I have tracks out of the current view port and it still hurts the performence

Any Suggestions? or thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instanced geometries three.js can not do any frustum culling as there is no information about where the objects will end up. This will be computed in the vertex-shader and three.js doesn't have any knowledge about what happens there.

The earliest possible time for any culling to happen is after running the vertex-shader for every vertex of every instance. This already explains the drop in framerate you're seeing. Although the same number of objects/triangles are visible, the number of vertex-shader invocations goes up to 166%.

If you want to implement culling yourself, you could try to rearrange the instances in the attribute-buffers for every frame (skip invisible instances) and adjust the max-instance count to the number of visible instances. That might be a bit counter-intuitive, but recomputing all instance-attribute buffers on every frame can actually give a better performance here.

To do the visibility-test, the simplest way would probably be to use the `THREE.Frustum()` class and `frustum.containsPoint()`. That would look something like this

```js
const frustum = new Frustum();
const projScreenMatrix = new Matrix();

// assume instances is an array of objects containing all the 
// relevant information for all instances
const instances = [
  // {position: ...}, {position: ...}, ...
];

// for every frame
projScreenMatrix.multiplyMatrices(
  camera.projectionMatrix, 
  camera.matrixWorldInverse 
);
frustum.setFromMatrix(projScreenMatrix);

let visibleInstanceCount = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < instanceCount; i++) {
  const pos = instances[i].position;

  if (!frustum.containsPoint(pos)) {
    continue;
  }

  // add instance to instance-attribute buffers
  pos.toArray(instancePositionBuffer, visibleInstanceCount * 3);
  visibleInstanceCount++;
}

geometry.maxInstanceCount = visibleInstanceCount;
```

Comment: That helps alot I'll give it a shot and see the performance difference, but makes complete sense. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, well My FPS nums at the top were wrong due to me misconfiguring it. But I am now gettings 27 FPS when viewing all tracks. When I use this soultion i still get 27 FPS when viewing all tracks but get 54 when viewing no tracks (I have other stuff rendering as well) So It shows in my case Little to no overhead. Extreamly cool Thanks!